# Java | Create an explicit addition function only using recursion and conditionals

Tags: java, recursion

**Preface**

By finding some free time in my schedule, I quested myself into improving my recursion skills (unfortunately). As practice, I want to recreate all the operators by using recursion, the first one being addition. Although I'm kind of stuck.

**Question**

As implied, I want to recreate the addition operator by only using recursion and conditionals. Although I got a good portion of the code done, there is still one problem as I included a single addition operator. Here is the code (which runs fine and adds as intended in all variations of positive, negative, and zero inputs). I also included some mediocre comments as help.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Numbers to add
        int firstNumb = -5, secondNumb = 3;
        // Call the add function and save the result
        int result = add(firstNumb, secondNumb);
        // Print result
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    /*
     * Function recursively takes a number from 'giver' one at a time and
     * "gives"/"adds" it to 'receiver'. Once nothing more to "give" (second == 0),
     * then return the number that received the value, 'receiver'.
     */
    public static int add(int receiver, int giver) {
        /*
         * Base Case since nothing more to add on. != to handle signed numbers
         * instead of using > or <
         */
        if (giver != 0) {
            /*
             * Recursive Call.
             * 
             * The new 'giver' param is the incremental value of the number
             * towards 0. Ex: -5 -> -4 , 5 -> 4 (so I guess it may decrement).
             * 
             * The new 'receiver' param is the incremental value based on the
             * opposite direction the 'giver' incremented (as to why the
             * directionalIncrement() function needs both values to determine
             * direction.
             */
            return add(directionalIncrement(receiver, giver),
                    directionalIncrement(giver, -giver));
        } else {
            // Return 'receiver' which now contains all values from 'giver'
            return receiver;
        }
    }

    // Increments (or decrements) the 'number' based on the sign of the 'direction'
    public static int directionalIncrement(int number, int direction) {
        // Get incremental value (1 or -1) by dividing 'direction' by absolute
        // value of 'direction'
        int incrementalValue = direction / abs(direction);
        // Increment (or decrement I guess)
        return number + incrementalValue;
    }

    // Calculates absolute value of a number
    public static int abs(int number) {
        // If number is positive, return number, else make it positive by multiplying by -1 then return
        number = (number > 0.0F) ? number : -number;
        return number;
    }
}
```

The problem is the line that contains `return number + incrementalValue;`. As mentioned before, the code works with this although doesn't meet my own specifications of not involving any addition operators.

I changed the line to `return add(number, incrementalValue);` but seems like it cannot break out of the recursion and indeed throws the title of this website, a `StackOverflowException.`

All help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Note**

Constraint does not include any implicit increment/decrement (i++/i--) nor does it include bitwise. Try and answer towards the specific problem I am having in my own implementation.

Comment: This is an interesting constrained programming problem; my hat off to you for that. If it helps I found a page that will help you perform addition using other bitwise operators [here](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/bitmath/). The problem is to implement that would require no recursion at all, so it wouldn't satisfy the constraint you've imposed on yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static int add(int a, int b) {
    if(b == 0) return a;
    int sum = a ^ b; //SUM of two integer is A XOR B
    int carry = (a & b) << 1;  //CARRY of two integer is A AND B
    return add(sum, carry);
}
```

Shamefully taken from [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.ch/2013/06/how-to-add-two-integer-numbers-without-plus-arithmetic-operator-java-example.html). All credit goes to its author.

Comment: Constraint does not involve bitwise operators even though it has recursion. Second, I'm trying to find an answer/solution towards the specific implementation in the question.

Comment: @codingbash If you don't want to use bitwise operators, you may have chosen the wrong language to achieve that as Java doesn't provide any other mean to sum 2 integers.

Comment: So are you suggesting that the question I specifically asked is unsolvable? I'm sure there is a way.

Comment: @codingbash I'm afraid it's unsolvable with your constraints.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int add (int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) return a;
    if (b > a) return add (b, a);
    add (++a, --b);
}
```

Just with ++/--.

Comment: I find that the same as doing a=a+1 which includes an addition operator. Not accepted

Comment: It's less addition than `number + incrementalValue` - it's just incrementation and just a unary operator.

Comment: You could work with String append and determine the string length in the end. Perhaps String.length works internally with addition/increment too.

Comment: These may all be wonderful solutions to the task, but it's not answering the question. I'm look for a solution to the specific problem I addressed in the code.

Comment: Well - it's not clear what you're addressing in your code. You're using a classical addition, aren't you? In 'add' you add (foo, bar(giver, -giver)) - the second is always 0, isn't it? So adding (foo, 0) should just be foo, shouldn't it? Why are you doing it though?

Comment: It is not calling the add function, it is calling the directionalIncrement function. The first parameter is the base number, the second number determines which way the base number increment towards (++/--).

Comment: Your add calls 2 times directionalIncrement, and dI uses the addition operator.